# .Net Core Web Catch All if a querystring value exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, routes

I did a controller to handle a single signin. It works when someone call a GET Url pointing to a controller WITH a "access_token" querystring containing its JWT (previously created on backend). It works well, and after checking JWT validation I create a user session and redirect then to a default Dashboard.

However, I want to accept this "access_token" querystring on ANY controller without need check this (like an if) on each function on whole system. So, I need to check if there is that querystring, if yes run the validation and signin functions and keep the user on the requested controller. It is like a single signin from any url just looking for a querystring.

I thought If I could use an Attribute on each controller or something on startup routing options... it does not make sense put an if on each controller function.

PS: This application uses default Cookie scheme for its authentication. The mentioned JWT is used by a Vue application to access another API after user is authenticated.

**The question is simple: Is there a way to "catch all" ANY url coming with access_token querystring and handle BEFORE Authorization Attribute? Like a pipeline: Request > HasQuerystringAndHandle > Authorization > Grant/Deny**

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer Yes, and long answer here: https://medium.com/@vaibhavrb999/jwt-authentication-authorization-in-net-core-3-1-e762a7abe00a

Comment: If you don't want to follow standard and instead pass jwt as a querystring variable, you properly need to do some middleware yourself.

Comment: @FrankNielsen thank you. But the application does not use the JWT to authenticate itself. The application uses default cookie scheme. This JWT is a token for another API which is checked when the user enter this application. So, after it check internally (going to backend API to validate) it creates a session using a cookie e also send this JWT as cookie to be used by Vue. So, I need to catch ANY access_token querystring from any controller and check before Authorization.

Comment: You can still do it, but you properly have to make it all by your self. My guess is that you can make your own jwt validation through you own middleware and similar `[Authorize(...)]` attribute to do validation on controller/route level.